# form button no manda su nombre-valor - JS, HTML, Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

he generado un pequeño formulario que consiste en un único botón usando javascript pero al enviar el formulario al backend no me lee el valor del botón, me devuelve null. Mi primer pensamiento fue que a lo mejor no podía enviar datos en un botón pero tras buscar por google vi en varias fuentes que sí se puede.

Código para generar el botón:

```js
let form = document.createElement("form");
form.action = "<%=application.getContextPath() + "/MyAds"%>";
form.method = "POST";

let buttonPublish = document.createElement("button");
buttonPublish.setAttribute("name", "status");
buttonPublish.setAttribute("type", "submit");
buttonPublish.setAttribute("value", "publish-" + post.id);
buttonPublish.classList.add("btn", "btn-primary", "btn-primary", "btn-fixed-size-100");
buttonPublish.innerText = "Publish";
                        
form.appendChild(buttonPublish);
div.appendChild(form);
```

HTML resultante:

```html
<form action="/p3/MyAds" method="POST">
    <button name="status" type="submit" value="publish-13" class="btn btn-primary btn-fixed-size-100">Publish</button>
</form>
```

Backend (Java servlet):

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("status")); //<-- Imprime null
    if (request.getAttribute("status") != null) {
        // Not implemented yet
    }
    else {              
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Los elementos del formulario HTTP llegan al Servlet como parámetros y no como atributos, tal vez te funcione así:

```
request.getParameter("status")
```